# ArcGIS Online:Unable to launch application: Unable to access application's configuration

Tags: arcgis-online

I have a custom configuration for an ArcGIS Online Web Application, and have followed all instructions.  I have changed the Web App settings and receive this message. 
**Unable to launch application: Unable to access application's configuration**
My JSON file is configured correctly.   What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a process which requires the user to publish an application template using a configured JSON file, that template then consumes ArcGIS Online Web-Maps.  It's important to make sure all parameters are set correctly within the JSON.  Very important caveat; when using a geocoder service, it is true to the extent of your consumed web map.